# Google analytics multiple domains using iframe content from 1 website

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, multiple-domains

I am running multiple domains all linking to the same iFrame content (an IBE).

I want to track traffic coming from all 3 of my domains, going into this single other website via the iFrame. I need to track when an online booking is completed which website it came from.

Currently on each of the three websites there is the following code (with the obvious change of the DomainName

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.my-example-domain-1.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

And on the domain of the booking engine I have the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*
        The cookie should only be created once when the page is first
        entered. After first view by the iframe, subsequent referrers will
        be from acumen.webapplications.com.
        The cookie will persist for a duration of one day.
    */

    if (document.referrer.toLowerCase().indexOf('my-example-domain-2.co.uk') > 0){
        createCookie('analyticsReferrer', 'my-example-domain-2', 1);
    }
    else if(document.referrer.toLowerCase().indexOf('my-example-domain-3.com') > 0){
        createCookie('analyticsReferrer', 'my-example-domain-3', 1);
    }
    else if(document.referrer.toLowerCase().indexOf('my-example-domain-1.com') > 0){
        createCookie('analyticsReferrer', 'my-example-domain-1', 1);
    }

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    try { 
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        if (readCookie('analyticsReferrer') === "my-example-domain-1"){
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-X']);
        }
        else if(readCookie('analyticsReferrer') === "my-example-domain-2"){
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-YYYYYYY-Y']);
        }
        else if(readCookie('analyticsReferrer') === "my-example-domain-3"){
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-ZZZZZZZ-Z']);
        }

        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mybookingenginedomain.com']); 
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() { 
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
        })();       

    } catch(err) {}
</script>
```

Could someone please shed some light on why bookings could potentially being attributed to the wrong domain, i.e. being credited to domain1 instead of domain2.

Comment: For anyone that's interested I actually figured out a solution to this when I discovered that cross domain scripting was a limitation of javascript and therefore the solution was to implement additional instances of the booking engine for each website to link to.